# Regex for splitting

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

I'd like to split a string such as

```
"[1-5]?3456[2-5][4-D]"
```

to

```
array[0] = "[1-5]"
array[1] = "?"
array[2] = "3"
array[3] = "4"
array[4] = "5"
array[5] = "6"
array[6] = "[2-5]"
array[7] = "[4-D]"
```

Can anybody tell me if that's possible with a regex that splits?

I got three elements "3" a letter (which can be 1-9 and A-F, "?" a whitecard, "[1-5]" a range (same 1-9 + A-F)

**Edit:** Examples that match are

```
"[1-5]?3456[2-5][4-D]"

"?4A9[1-F]?[A-D]1"

"12459987"

"[1-F][1-F][1-F][1-F][1-F][1-F][1-F][1-F]"
```

Comment: Can you give us some example strings that matches your pattern?

Comment: /([0-9A-F?]|\\[[0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F]\\])([0-9A-F?]|\\[[0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F]\\])([0-9A-F?]|\\[[0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F]\\])([0-9A-F?]|\\[[0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F]\\])([0-9A-F?]|\\[[0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F]\\])([0-9A-F?]|\\[[0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F]\\])([0-9A-F?]|\\[[0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F]\\])([0-9A-F?]|\\[[0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F]\\])/
works but is a bit ugly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tested with [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm):

```
(\[[^]]+\])|.
```

To use this expression to get the splits, you can use the following code:

```
var input = "[1-5]?3456[2-5][4-D]";
var pattern = new Regex(@"(\[[^]]+\])|(.)", 
                        RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);

IEnumerable<string> parts = from m in pattern.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
                            select m.Captures[0].Value;
```

Comment: The difference between my answer and Richard's is that his will return an empty bracket pair together as "[]" whereas mine will split it into 2 results "[","]".

Comment: pattern is unknown vs tells me...how can that be?

Comment: Upvoted yours, since you beat me to a fully-functional answer. However, right now the expression has some extra backslashes in it (from before you indented it into a code block). I did think the OP would probably rather have an empty [] set than individual characters, but both solutions have merit depending on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

```
\[[^]]*\]|.
```

Comment: splits every character single

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string pattern = @"(\[[1-9A-F?]-[1-9A-F?]\])|[1-9A-F?]";
string input = "[1-5]?3456[2-5][4-D]";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```